# mat-table auto fit column width to bigger content

Tags: angular, css

I have a mat-table I want to auto fit column width, anyone will be as long as the longest column content.

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

 <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="myHeader"> No. </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="myCell"> {{element.email}} </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="myHeader"> Name </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="myCell"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>

</mat-table>
```

Data example:

```
const DATA: Data[] = [
 {email: 'mail1@mail.com', name: 'Long name for this person'},
 {email: 'mail2@mail.com': 'name2',
 {email: 'longmailaddres@longmailaddress.com: 'name3'}
];
```

So, width cells will be enough for "longmailaddress@longmailaddres.com" and for "Long name for this person".

My choices doesnt work, I tried with FxFlexFill and fxFlex unsucced this is my css unsucced option.

```
.myHeader, .myCell{
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You want it in single line or breaks are fine ?

Comment: I'd prefer single line

Comment: Why not do it with CSS ? Also post a working example if possible.

Comment: @cucuru is there any way to define same size for the column even screen size changes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296518/how-to-support-same-column-size-when-screen-size-reducing-in-angular-material-ta

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You've probably solved this by now, but posting here for anyone else who might come across this.

I used this for reference:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5808

It's not an auto-sizing column, but this is how you set widths on specific `mat-table`columns (the contents wrap by default):

```css
mat-cell:nth-child(1),
mat-header-cell:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 0 0 30%;
}

mat-cell:nth-child(5),
mat-header-cell:nth-child(5) {
    flex: 0 0 10%;
}
```

If you want to use auto-sizing you'll have to use native `<table>` as per the solution on this issue:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5866

Comment: Hey @srukali did you find a better solution in the last year or is this still the best solution? Using this rn and not looking good.

Comment: @Raymo111 I have not looked for another solution, this one is still in place in our codebase. If you're worried about responsiveness, we remove columns as it gets smaller.

Comment: I see. So by nth child what do you mean?

Comment: @Raymo111 It refers to the number of the column (starting from 1 not 0). It'll be easy to see if you play around with the numbers

Comment: Do I just call it with nth-child(col#)?

Comment: @ metalkat is there any way to define same size for the column even screen size changes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296518/how-to-support-same-column-size-when-screen-size-reducing-in-angular-material-ta

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-footer-row,
.mat-header-row,
.mat-row {
    display: inline-flex;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

copied from https://fireflysemantics.medium.com/making-the-angular-material-data-table-rows-fit-content-f227f4d9355e