# Angular Material Table Width 100%

Tags: angular

I'm using material table inside angular material card. Here is my code:

```html
<mat-card style="margin: 5px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;font-size:10px !important;" class="mat-elevation-z15"
  fxFlex>
  <mat-card-content fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between" fxFlex>
    <h4>Incidents</h4>
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Number</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.number }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="desc">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Description</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.desc }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="assn_group">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Group</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.assn_group }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="product">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Product</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.product }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>State</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.state }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="opened">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Opened</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.opened }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="sla_group">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>SLA Group</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.sla_group }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </mat-table>


  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

And the table width set to 100%. it gets extended fully in the code but the columns not fully using the 100% of the table width

Attaching table screenshot

[image: Screenshot of the table]

Comment: Take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684560/mat-table-auto-fit-column-width-to-bigger-content

Comment: @ChrisM. for some reason even after using the css in my code, i don see any difference to the way how the table appears

Comment: I fixed it by adding fxFlex to the cell header and cell

Comment: where should we add fxFlex? can you provide a sample? I  added like an attribute and it didn't work

Answer (score 9):

I know that this question is old, but I had the same problem, and this worked for me.

`mat-table` contains a class name `mat-table` where you can specify some styles, adding the property of "table", you can add some style in this case

```
table.mat-table {
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Just faced this issue after filtering the table data. Setting display: table to <mat-table> fixed the issue. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Style that worked for me is as below:

```
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
display: table;
```

Comment: I got rid of `table-layout` property and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Since this [feature](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/10594)
you can use the native table element followed by `mat-table`. See also official [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#:%7E:text=%3Ctable%20mat%2Dtable%20%5BdataSource%5D%3D%22myDataArray%22%3E%0A%20%20...%0A%3C/table%3E)

```
<table mat-table>
    your table
</table>
```

vs the old not very responsive way:

```
<mat-table>
    your table
</mat-table>
```

When using the native element table:

> enables key features such as auto column resizing, col/row span, easy copy/paste (cells map into spreadsheets easily)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the style file. it works.

```
.mat-table {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.mat-cell,
.mat-header-cell {
    word-wrap: initial;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
    line-break: unset;
    width: auto; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.mat-row,
.mat-header-row {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding a utility class did worked for me.

```
.w-100 {
 width: 100%;
}

<table mat-table class="w-100">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header>Name</th>
            <td *matCellDef="let row" mat-cell>{{row.name}}</td>
          </ng-container>
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @Kainka can you share code snippet? so i can help you out.