# Angular 6 material ui table ful width

Tags: angular6, mat-table

I have a table inside a mat-card but the content of the table is not in full width.

setting the table as widht: 100% doesn't work

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 resultsTable">
    <ng-container class="col-2" matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID gestión </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container class="col-2" matColumnDef="solicitante">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Solicitante </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.solicitante}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container class="col-2" matColumnDef="tipoTramite">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tipo de trámite </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.tipoTramite}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container class="col-3" matColumnDef="fechaAsignacion">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fecha de asignación </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fecha}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container class="col-2" matColumnDef="encargadoActual">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Encargado actual </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.encargadoActual}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</mat-table>
```

Comment: Hello! Did you search StackOverflow for other answers first? I found this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746555/angular-material-table-width-100 where the person is using flex.

Comment: Can you share your css and post a snapshot of your screen and if possible create a stackblitz for it

Answer (score 4):

The problem was solved by replacing
`<mat-table>` with `<table mat-table` and setting the width to 100%