# Angular Material Table doesn't take all width

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have the Angular Material Table. It doesn't work properly. It' doesn't take the whole width. How could I force it to take the entire width?

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.position }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.weight }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.symbol }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Just for reference you can take a look at this post- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746555/angular-material-table-width-100

Comment: Thank you, but it's not my problem actually. My problem is that the entire table doesn't take all width, not just columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(should be a comment will delete later)

did you try:

`table { width: 100%!important; }` 
?

Comment: yes, but it's not a good practice with !important. I'm trying something different

Answer (score 2):

As you have it, it is as specified in the [Table | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-basic) documentation  so that it takes the entire width. You might have a parent div or container with a smaller width property and therefore your table is not taking all the space. If you don't want to force it with the `important!` tag, try to investigate that in your HTML code.

You can also try to use the flex version for the table [Tables with display: flex | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#tables-with-display-flex) nevertheless it is not compatible with some native features for the table component.